# Google Drive app(Grive) do not synchronize all directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grive

The problem is , after installation Google Drive app(Grive)  not all directories and files are beeing synchronized. It is Grive Tools (Version 1.10 beta) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64. In particular to Android synchronization app it works perfectly.